# Axapta Enterprise portal 2012 installation

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to install Enterprise Portal on my local p.c. and i am getting this error message. 
Any help

This is from the log file.

```
    2012-12-28 06:32:16Z    An error occurred during setup of Enterprise Portal (EP).
    2012-12-28 06:32:16Z    Reason: The Web site '' was not created correctly. 
    The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Thanks
Shaik

Answer (score 0):

Is your website setup in Ax done correctly and does validating those settings from within Ax work?